# Home button press , Which AppDelegate method should i use for scheduling a local notification

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I would like to schedule a local notification as soon as the user hits the home button.

Which App delegate method should I use in this case :

- applicationWillResignActive
- applicationDidEnterBackground
- applicationWillTerminate

Well I guess I shouldn't use the third one, but what is the difference between the first two ?

Is there any way to distinguish getting interrupted by a phone call/other notification and actually pressing the home button ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To schedule local notification you shold use `applicationDidEnterBackground` instead of using `applicationWillResignActive` because `applicationWillResignActive` call every time when app get some specific interruption line phone call, sms. You want to schedule notification when user press home button and in this case `applicationDidEnterBackground` is the appropriate place to do this.

One thing that should be remember before using `applicationDidEnterBackground` is that this delegate has `approximately five seconds to perform any task`, if any task in this delegate will take more time then os will terminate your app. You can also request for additional time for execution by using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` and then use a secondary thread to perform a task. For more detail about application delegates follow the links -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/

Answer (score 2):

You should use applicationDidEnterBackground.

applicationWillResignActive gets called anytime your app is interrupted such as a phone call or SMS message. In this case if the user ignores these then your app will keep running in the foreground.

applicationDidEnterBackground only gets called when your app actually goes to the background.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in applicationDidEnterBackground:

- applicationWillTerminate will not be
  called when the user hits the home
  button. With app switching this is
  only sent when the user explicitly
  quits the app or possibly in low
  memory situations.
- applicationWillResignActive is
  additionally called when the app is
  briefly interrupted, say by an SMS or
  phone call alert. (Though if the user
  then switches to Messages or Phone
  app your app will eventually get a
  applicationDidEnterBackground
  message).

So it sounds like you're specifically interested in the point when the user taps the home button and the app goes to the background. applicationDidEnterBackground is the place.

You could also always schedule the local notification and only respond to it if the app isn't running when it occurs. Not better necessarily, just an option to consider.