# How to perform an action after closing the app?

Tags: ios, delegates, performselector

How can I perform an action after hitting the home button?
I guess I have to add some code to the AppDelegate?
Is it possible to do some code like?:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(selector)];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why perform selector? What have you tried? What did it do wrong?

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the answer here should point you in the right direction: [Home button press...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114077/home-button-press-which-appdelegate-method-should-i-use-for-scheduling-a-local)

Answer (score 2):

Use `applicationWillResignActive:` method in appDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to 
    // inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary 
    // interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) 
    // or when the user quits the application and it begins the 
    // transition to the background state.

    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, 
    // and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use 
    // this method to pause the game.
}
```

Or second option is to use `applicationDidEnterBackGround:`

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, 
    // invalidate timers, and store enough application state information 
    // to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 

    // If your application supports background execution, 
    // this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```

Depends ofcourse, what you want to do. Those comments are straight quotes from Apple's code template.

---

## To access your view controller's methods:

```
MyViewController *vController = (MyViewController *)[_window rootViewController];
[vController pause];
```

Your error told you that you don't have `pause` method in your App Delegate class.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I have already tried putting the [self perform...]; code in those AppDelegate statements and every time it ends up with the ERROR:
----
2013-11-17 12:34:36.057 Castle[308:60b] -[AppDelegate pause]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15579a30
2013-11-17 12:34:36.066 Castle[308:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppDelegate pause]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15579a30' 
----
How can I add a line of code which interacts with the viewController.m?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data,invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}
```